# Does the word "concurrent" imply only two conditions?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

If I wanted to imply that at any given time I'm managing many projects of different durations that overlap, is it redundant to say "I manage multiple concurrent projects"?  Does "numerous concurrent" sound less ridiculous?

Comment: Why not “multiple overlapping?” Concurrent suggests *at the same time*. Look it up.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with "multiple concurrent projects" in a general sense - it makes it clear you mean more than two projects. But I wouldn't describe them as "concurrent" unless every project overlapped with every other one, which seems unlikely if they have different durations.

Answer (score 3):

Neither Lexico nor Chambers confines the use of *concurrent* to only two simultaneous events or processes.  Indeed the first example at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/concurrent) is

> *there are three concurrent art fairs around the city*

while Chambers defines the word to mean

> *running, coming, acting or existing together or simultaneously*.

It's a mite redundant to include the word *concurrent* in your sentence *I manage multiple concurrent projects*, I think the use of *manage* in the present tense implies that you manage them at the same, current, time. But it's a small nit to pick at and I wouldn't have thought twice about it if your question hadn't raised the issue.

And on the axis of ridiculosity *numerous concurrent* scores higher than *multiple concurrent*, ie is more ridiculous to this reader.